# How to know if a syslog message was sent properly using log4j without relying on exceptions

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, syslog

I'm using log4j in order to send syslog message to a syslog server.

In case the syslog message was not sent properly (e.g the syslog serve is down), an exception is thrown which is great because I have indication.

I have a case where I send syslog message over TCP and a firewall on the syslog server is blocking me BUT no Exception is thrown.

I would like to know when a message is being blocked like that.

is there anyway to know if a message was sent properly without relying on exceptions?

Maybe there is a different framework to send syslog message that can provide me the information I need?

below you can find my current code if it help.

```
private Logger configureSyslog(SyslogSendProtocolType protocol, SyslogFacilityType syslogFacilityType, String host, int port, boolean ignoreExceptions, String appenderName, String loggerName) {
    try {
        LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
        SyslogAppender itpSyslogAppender = SyslogAppender.createAppender(host,
                port,
                protocol.name(),
                null,
                0,
                0,
                true,
                appenderName,
                true,
                ignoreExceptions,
                Facility.toFacility(syslogFacilityType.name()),
                null,
                Rfc5424Layout.DEFAULT_ENTERPRISE_NUMBER,
                true,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                true,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                config,
                Charset.forName("UTF-8"),
                null,
                new LoggerFields[]{},
                false);

        itpSyslogAppender.start();
        config.addAppender(itpSyslogAppender);
        AppenderRef[] refs = new AppenderRef[]{AppenderRef.createAppenderRef(appenderName, null, null)};
        LoggerConfig loggerConfig = LoggerConfig.createLogger("false", Level.DEBUG, loggerName,
                "true", refs, null, config, null);
        loggerConfig.addAppender(itpSyslogAppender, null, null);
        config.removeLogger(loggerName);
        config.addLogger(loggerName, loggerConfig);

        ctx.updateLoggers();
        return ctx.getLogger(loggerName);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        LOGGER.error("An error occurred while configuring syslog settings");
        LOGGER.trace("Exception: ", e);
        throw e;
    }
}

public synchronized void sendSyslog(String msg, SyslogSendLevelType level) {
    System.out.println("sending syslog");
    Logger sysLogger = configureSyslog(protocol, syslogFacilityType, host, port, false, SYSLOG_APPENDER_NAME, ITP_LOGGER_NAME);
    try {
        sysLogger.log(levelsMapping.get(level), msg);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("syslog message cannot be sent");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The SyslogAppender extends the SocketAppender, so both are just using TCP. First, you have OS buffering where the message being sent might reside in the client until the buffer is flushed long after your application has moved on. Then the firewall might get the message and simply discard it or it might acknowledge it, in which case you will never know it wasn't received. Even without the firewall there is no guarantee that the receiving application hasn't crashed and the OS hasn't yet closed the socket. In short, only a protocol that requires the application to acknowledge every message can provide a guarantee to the client that it was received. Syslog is not that protocol.